# Calling a procedure for each row - Report builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a query in a report that returns some ids , department names, etc. For each id returned i want to fill another column in the report with the result of a procedure. So for each row i need to call a procedure with the ID as a parameter. Any idea on how could i solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you working on core php?? you should use join query

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as described in your query.  Your options are

1. Return the results of the second stored procedure as part of the original call to the dataset.
2. Create a second dataset that returns all the potential values for the new column (as if you had passed each ID in separately) and the ID of which row they would relate to, and use Lookup to join the two datasets together.